# JavaScript - Basic Implementation of xCharts

Tags: javascript, php, xcharts

I've just found out about the xCharts and trying to learn it myself from the Documentation of official page. I've applied the below code for the basic show so I could use this Charts later on, but the chart simply not showing up in the figure. Any ideas? Thanks.

My Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <figure style="width: 300px; height: 300px" id="myChart"></figure>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/xcharts.css"></script>
        <script src="js/xcharts.js">
            var data = {
                "xScale": "ordinal",
                "yScale": "linear",
                "type": "bar",
                "main": [
                    {
                        "className": ".pizza",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "x": "Pepperoni",
                                "y": 12
                            },
                            {
                                "x": "Cheese",
                                "y": 8
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "comp": [
                    {
                        "className": ".pizza",
                        "type": "line-dotted",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "x": "Pepperoni",
                                "y": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "x": "Cheese",
                                "y": 4
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };
            var myChart = new xChart('bar',datai,'#myChart');
        </script>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
    </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     var data = {
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>        var myChart = new xChart('bar',datai,'#myChart');
> ```

Your variable-name above is "data" not "datai" as used below